# Read Input hidden tag value from url of website using Jsoup in java

Tags: java, jsoup

I am writing a Java application which tries to fetch contents from a web page. I try to write code which is given below.

When I try to fetch all links(html `<a>` tag) from the website my code works well,
but when I try to fetch a value from `input type="hidden"` tag I have a problem.

```
 String url = "http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/pc-repair-%3Cnear%3E-jp-nagaer";
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
 Elements input = doc.select("a[href]");
 System.out.print(input);
```

This code works fine.. it gives all the links included in this website.. but I want the value from `input type="hidden"`. What to do I have to do?

If I do `doc.select("input[hidden]")` then result comes with a `null` value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use

```
doc.select("input[type=hidden]")
```

to get the tags you want. Your proposed version will return all `<input hidden="..">` tags not those with `<input type="hidden">`.